# Chrome Hard Reload using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

We have developed an AungularJS browser based app and testing with a Client (a group of people from client side), it is hard to convince them, how to "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" (Press F12, then on top right click on Refresh button and choose -Empty Cache and Hard Reload),

For the time, we are testing only on Chrome browser, is there any way to do that using JS, ask to press "Hard reset button" (like document.location.reload(true);)

[image]

Comment: You can also just press Ctrl + F5, should be simple enough for your clients, I hope..

Comment: no that don't do "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access outside your own page (gladly), so you cant click outside your own page window to click on the refresh button.

The best thing you can do is set html tags to let the browser know that it don't may use caching.

Add the following between your `<head> </head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="mon, 22 jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: I'd rather go with a serversided solution that if a certain parameter is present that is hadded to the headers and in the metadata. You dont want a constant refresh, you also need to see how the page works with cached files.