# Can we enable or disable the hard reload menu in chrome using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reload

This question might seem repeated, but I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088922/chrome-hard-reload-using-js) question, but I still have some questions remaining that are making me more and more curious about the working behind this logic. As it is a browser property, I think we cannot make changes to it using JS or jQuery, but I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on this.

Here is the screenshot of the menu that I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot of the popup menu displaying normal and hard reload]

I have the following questions regarding this:

1. Why does this popup appear for some links and does not appears for other? For example if I login into my sandbox and then go to the storefront, I have the option to do a hard reload but for the others this popup never appears.
2. In the question that I tagged above, they have disabled the cache in order to disable the hard reload popup, how does it work?

I have also gone through some questions suggesting that we can disable the keys like `Ctrl + F5`, `Ctrl + R`, `Ctrl + Shift + R` or `Ctrl + Shift + F5`, but what can be done to disable/enable the menu if the someone long press the reload button or right click on it?

I don't have a requirement or issue regarding this. I am just curious as this question have been bugging me from a week or so.

If someone has a take on this, please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Some people will say it is a duplicate question but its not as I have gone through most of those questions, but I was hoping for an answer suggesting if we can enable or disable that question using JS/jQuery or not. So I guess that question is still unanswered.

Comment: yes I am sure, I dont have any extension

Comment: That menu only appears when your developer tools are open.

Comment: but if we work on demandware integration, then most of the storefronts have this function. But the same doesnt work if we try to open someone else' storefront.

Comment: @Archer, what is the answer, I cannot see it.

Comment: So, is there a way to enable or disable it using JS or jQuery? Still my question is unanswered. @Archer

Comment: It is not a bug or an issue, I am just curious. @Archer

Comment: No - there is nothing you can do with Javascript.  Close your developer tools and it will disappear.

Comment: @Archer thanks for that fact, I didnt knew about this, I guess there is a lot to learn about, so is there a way by which we can block that from happening?

Comment: @Code_Ninja No it is not possible to have any influence on that menu/the devtools with JS. The most you can do as far as I'm aware is checking whether the dev tools are open or not. ([And even that is a bit of a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open))

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { event.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: okay thanks for the link @Ivar , I think now I can match the dots.